# Menu-commands extension for Visual Studio without command-table

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-2019

I am building a Visual Studio extension (VSIX) with menu commands depending on the options for the extension. Its dynamic, what commands (how many) depends on the options.

I have a solution for it that uses the command-table, like: [Dynamically add menu items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/dynamically-adding-menu-items?view=vs-2019)

I would like to skip the command-table and build the menus totally programmatically, like: [HOWTO: Package with commands created by code](https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/PackageCommandsCreatedByCode)

The reason is to make it more dynamic. So if the user adds/changes/deletes in the options of the extension it would be handled dynamically (programmatically). On saving options the menu-command tree would be rebuildt. If I use a command-table I will have to add/delete nodes there to be able to solve it.

The thing I can not figure out is howto add the objects for "groups" and "menus" programmatically.

So I am out for the class/interface that has "AddGroup" or "AddMenu" as methods.

Is this at all possible or do I have to use the command-table? If it is possible I would appreciate links to code-examples for it.

Regards Hans

Comment: They just MenuItems (VsMenuItem). I had such dynamic menu some times ago. I created them manually. Get `Type VsMenuItem = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsMenuItem");`. Create menuitems `var mi = CreateInstance(VsMenuItem);`, subscribe for `Click` event, put them into `ObservableCollection<MenuItem> subMenu`. And set collection to menu from vsct `menuItem.ItemsSource = subMenu` Of course it's not good way but you do all manually.

Comment: @vik_78 Thank you for your comment
As I understand it, the "vsct" (command-table) is needed for this solution. I am out for a solution without a vsct-file.

Comment: Yes. In `vsct` you need to create menu and "place holder" inside menu. Because menu will be disabled if it doesn't contains elements. After setting `ItemsSource` placeholder will be replaces with new items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVP Carlos Quintero has published sample code using IVsProfferCommmands3.AddNamedCommand that illustrates how to programmatically add menu items via the automation services (formerly utilized by the now discontinued add-in extensibility model).

https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/PackageCommandsCreatedByCode

While add-ins are no longer supported, the automation interfaces are still present. So you can use these, bearing in mind these menu items (aka commands) are temporary.

Also, the sample code here is a little outdated, using Package instead of AsyncPackage, and ProvideAutoLoad attributes. So you'll also want to read up on the following:

https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/AsyncPackageMigration
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/

Sincerely,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Carlos example (PackageCommandsCreatedByCode) I have looked at as I mentioned in my question. I am out for building the menu structure in code. Adding groups and menus because they depend on what the user have added in the options for the extension. That is, adding <Group> and <Menu> object by code without the *.vsct file.

Comment: Adding vsct based resources dynamically/programmatically isn't possible. .VSCT files are compiled into an embedded resource that the IDE scans and subsequently caches (for performance reasons). Rebuilding menu UI every time your package loads, incurs an unwanted performance hit, that negatively impacts startup and project load times. Hence the static nature of menus/commands.

Comment: As I understood the PackageCommandsCreatedByCode-example was that it was possible to create a command by code. A command is normally vsct-based but the example shows a way to do it by code. But if you say it is not possible to create <Group> and <Menu> objects by code I have to trust you. So I mark this "thread" as the answer.

Comment: [`AddNamedCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.commands.addnamedcommand?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) is now obsolete in VS 2022, any alternatives?